# Android/Cordova build dependency error with google-play-services (more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms')

Tags: android, cordova, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, cordova-plugins

Note: I know there are a thousand questions about this error on SO, and I swear I've read all of them, but none of the solutions have worked. (More detail on my many unsuccessful attempts below.)

When I try to build my cordova app for Android, I get the following error:

```
:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'
  You can temporarily disable this error with android.enforceUniquePackageName=false
  However, this is temporary and will be enforced in 1.0
```

My question: How can I fix this and build my app?

**Background**

From the many SO answers I've read, I know this is almost certainly a problem with plugins adding duplicate Google Play dependencies. My app (and all its plugins) were working great until my most recent plugin addition: the [Urban Airship cordova plugin](https://github.com/urbanairship/phonegap-ua-push). Here is my current plugin list:

```
cc.fovea.cordova.purchase 4.0.0 "Purchase"
com.xmartlabs.cordova.market 1.1 "Market"
cordova-google-play-services 25.0.0 "Google Play Services for Android"
cordova-plugin-analytics 1.3.3 "Google Analytics Plugin"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.2 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.0 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.2.0 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-file 3.0.0 "File"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.1.1 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.1.0 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.0.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.0.0 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.0 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.0.7.1 "SocialSharing"
cordova-plugin-x-toast 2.3.1 "Toast"
urbanairship-cordova 4.0.1 "Urban Airship"
```

I've read through every plugin's plugin.xml, and the only other one which references Google Play Services is [Appfeel's cordova-plugin-analytics](https://github.com/appfeel/analytics-google/blob/master/plugin.xml).

I'm using cordova 5.4.1 and cordova-android@4.1.1. Here is [my config.xml](http://pastebin.com/XBrAJPnK). I'm not using an IDE.

Also, another answer recommended investigating the compile dependencies and looking for duplicates using `./gradlew dependencies`. Doing so gave me [this output](http://pastebin.com/GGwM3LYj). As you can see, it has many duplicates: lots of com.google.android.gms and lots of com.android.support and lots of CordovaLib.

**What I've tried**

1. Removing and re-adding the Android platform. It changed nothing.
2. Removing and re-adding cordova-google-play-services. I was unable to remove it and got the following error:

   ```
   Error: The plugin 'cordova-google-play-services' is required by (cordova-plugin-analytics), skipping uninstallation.
   ```

   (I did not install cordova-google-play-services explicitly – it was installed automatically by cordova-plugin-analytics.)

   Earlier in my project I tried to use the more common analytics plugins by [danwilson](https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin) and [cmackay](https://github.com/cmackay/google-analytics-plugin), but I ran into similar issues just *installing* those plugins, which is why I'm now using Appfeel's Google Analytics plugin (which installed without problems and works great).
3. Adding a build-extras.gradle in /platforms/android with the following code:

   ```
   configurations {
     all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
     all*.exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-analytics'
   }
   ```

   When I run this, I *do* avoid the "more than one library" error, but instead I get dozens of package-does-not-exist errors like this one:

   ```
   :compileDebugJava
   /Users/sarah/Development/app/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/cordova/CordovaAutopilot.java:31: error: package android.support.v4.app does not exist
   import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
                            ^
   ```

   I've also tried a variety of other exclusion combinations that were motivated from the `./gradlew dependencies` output I mentioned above.
4. Updating the Android platform, updating cordova
5. Making sure I have the most current version of gradle
6. Updating everything I can in the Android SDK Manager. Here's a [screenshot of the Extras I have installed](https://cl.ly/122L1r3v3R0s). And a [screenshot of Tools](http://cl.ly/332K1m1O1k3X). And [other SDK packages](http://cl.ly/323D04462x0t).
7. Adding a build-extras.gradle that uses `dependencies` with exclusions instead of `configurations`. I've tried about twenty different combinations of packages and groups and modules (again motivated by the `./gradlew dependencies` output) . Sometimes I try excluding only groups or only modules. Sometimes I try excluding with or without the version numbers. (As you can see, I don't really know what I'm doing re:gradle.) Here's one attempt:

   ```
   dependencies {
       compile('com.urbanairship.android:urbanairship-sdk:6.4.1') {
           exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
           exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-basement'
           exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
       }
   }
   ```

   Here's another:

   ```
   dependencies {
       compile('com.urbanairship.android:urbanairship-sdk:6.4.1') {
           exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
           exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
           exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-basement'
           exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
       }

       compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0') {
           exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
           exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
           exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-basement'
           exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
       }

       compile('com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0') {
           exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
       }
   }
   ```
8. In my research I discovered that the Urban Airship plugin has [its own build-extras.gradle](https://github.com/urbanairship/phonegap-ua-push/blob/master/src/android/build-extras.gradle) in /platforms/android/urbainairship-cordova. So I tried adding compile exclusions to *that* build-extras.gradle instead using a zillion combinations like those I mentioned in #7. Eventually I exclude too much and end up with package-does-not-exist errors like those shown in #3, but backing off results in the same more-than-one-library error.
9. Commenting out `<dependency id="cordova-google-play-services" />` in the [analytics plugin's plugin.xml](https://github.com/appfeel/analytics-google/blob/master/plugin.xml#L40).

**My question**

Sorry for the long post, but this all seems like relevant troubleshooting info! To restate my question from the beginning: how do I fix this error and build successfully?

Comment: OP here. I'm still having my build error with the Urban Airship plugin and every other push-notif plugin that I could, but I finally was able to install one that didn't give me this problem: https://github.com/ropilz/phonegap-parse-plugin (and I had to setup a Parse account). 

I did have problems with crashing when receiving a notif while the app was in the background, but I fixed them by following the Android setup instructions from this *other* plugin: https://github.com/ropilz/phonegap-parse-plugin 

I'd still rather use Urban Airship and find the answer, but hopefully this helps someone.

Comment: You may also look at this fix http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34775891/error-more-than-one-library-with-package-name-com-google-android-gms-using-co/34776219#34776219

Comment: Thank you, @Sunil, I will try this!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this recently with `com.android.support` conflicts and (for that)
I would highly recommend https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-support-gradle-release which is a "plugin to align various versions of the Android Support libraries specified by other plugins".

To avoid the problem of removing *all* versions of the support libs, which can lead plugins having missing dependencies/failing gradle syncs, they use some [clever gradle dependency resolution](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-support-gradle-release/blob/master/cordova-android-support-gradle-release.gradle#L27) to solve the problem:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        if (details.requested.group in ['com.android.support'] && !(details.requested.name in ['multidex', 'multidex-instrumentation'])) { details.useVersion "26.1.0"}
    }
}
```

I reckon you could do the same for your Google Plays Services libs by adding another inner condition:

```
if (details.requested.group in ['com.google.android.gms'] && !(details.requested.name in ['multidex', 'multidex-instrumentation'])) {
    details.useVersion "11.8.0" //Or whichever GMS level you're targeting.
}
```